# How should I lift the umbrella on a white Crepe Myrtle tree?

Tags: trees, pruning

What is the best pruning technique to lift the umbrella on a white [Crepe Myrtle](https://garden.org/plants/group/crepe-myrtles/) tree?

Comment: Need pictures for sure.  Take one looking up into the umbrella or canopy and one of the whole tree.  How long has this tree been in the spot it is in now?  Have you ever fertilized?

Comment: depends on the size of the plant- will need a photo to advise.